# Is an .onion service aware of its own circuit?

Tags: onion-services, anonymity, relays, onion-routing, log

So I understand that when a user logs into an onion service, **they are logged as *”127.0.0.1”* and port**

*now*, **does the onion service log the relays** or know what relays it connected to in order to establish this connection? **Is it possible to configure it this way and log specific circuits?**

Asking from the server side

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not - directly, but using `Stem` library you can traverse it if needed